# Function inside a script tag inserted via javascript remains undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined-function

My problem is that when I create a script tag trough javascript

```
    var script = document.createElement('script');      
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.getElementById("fastexe").appendChild (script);
```

(the div parent of the script is before this script), and I insert a function in it like so

```
    script.innerHTML = "function in_my_script(){ \n";
    script.innerHTML += "alert('test'); \n }";
```

when I try to call my function (function_in_my_script) through the console or even like this:

```
    script.innerHTML += "\n function_in_my_script();";
```

I get a function not defined error, for apparently no reason. I tried with different function names, nothing inside of the function and different alerts in the function but nothing changed the result.

I don't understand why the function stays undefined. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What browser are you doing this in? Afaik, some have problems with `innerHTML` on script elements

Comment: You should try filling the script element before appending it to the DOM. Afaik that's the only time when it will be evaluated.

Comment: Your function is called `in_my_script`, not `function_in_my_script`. If this is just example code, please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you append a string to the `SCRIPT` element's innerHTML, the browser tries to run the element.  This leads to a syntax error when the `SCRIPT` is simply `function in_my_script(){`.

Instead, build the script's contents in a variable, and then add it to `script.innerHTML` all at once:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script'),
    s;

script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
document.getElementById("fastexe").appendChild(script);

s = "function in_my_script(){ \n";
s += "alert('test'); \n }";
s += "\n in_my_script();";

script.innerHTML= s;
```

```html
<div id="fastexe"></div>
```

Comment: Working ! Thank you really much, never tought it could be interpreted that way !